# Why doesn't my ngIf condition function work?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, conditional-statements

I am trying to carry out a condition: if the data that comes from the data matrix is = "Inversión" you must put a value for me, if it is = "Funcionamiento" you must put another value, and if there is nothing it is because there is an error! Here I leave part of the code.

HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let dato of dataRoute">
  <td mat-cell colspan="2" *ngIf="recurso(dato.tipoGasto)" style="text-align: center; vertical- 
  align: middle;">
           {{recurso(dato.tipoGasto)}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

TS:

```
recurso() {
    if(this.dataRoute.tipoGasto == "Inversión"){
      return "[10] RECURSOS CORRIENTES"
    }
    if(this.dataRoute.tipoGasto == "Funcionamiento"){
      return "[11] OTROS RECURSOS DEL TESORO"
    }
    else {
      return " Error! "
    }
  }
```

It is ALWAYS getting "Error!". I did a debug and in this.dataRoute there is the data, however in this.dataRoute.tipoGasto there is nothing, it appears "undefined".

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What are you attempting to pass to the function from the markup? Your function definition doesn't have any arguments. You should either pass a value or use the state data, but not both.

Comment: `*ngIf` just get boolean type not string!

Answer (score 0):

1. `*ngIf` works a bit differently than your goal. Hence your function always returns a string, it does not matter what kind of string, it will be casted to `true`.
2. Your `recurso` function does not accepts any parameter - this is another problem.

What you are trying to achieve could be better solved with an `ngSwitch` and with some code updates.

```
<tr *ngFor="let dato of dataRoute">
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="recurso(dato.tipoGasto)">
    <td mat-cell colspan="2" *ngSwitchCase="'[10] RECURSOS CORRIENTES'">{{recurso(dato.tipoGasto)}}</td>
    <td mat-cell colspan="2" *ngSwitchCase="'[11] OTROS RECURSOS DEL TESORO'">{{recurso(dato.tipoGasto)}}</td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

But hence you always loop through your options, it worth double check your logic. Other solution, just to simply output the calculated value.

```
<tr>
    <td mat-cell colspan="2">{{recurso(dataRoute.tipoGasto)}}</td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps you, but comment if you have any other questions. My other suggestions are:

1. Program always in English - that is the universal language for that, and if you have to ask on StakcOverflow, it is much easier to find someone who will answear.
2. Does not rely on values like `[10] RECURSOS CORRIENTES` in your `ngSwitch` case - use something simpler.

**EDIT**

If you are looping over the `dataRoute` dataset, it must be a type of `Array` if Angular handles this four you out of the box. You simply can not read `this.dataRoute.tipoGasto` from that. It returns `undefined` then always the last `else` branch will return for you. So the very first problem is the `if` statements of your function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @vazsonyidl! Indeed my `dataRoute` is an `array`, so how could I solve my problem from the TS?